# How to schedule event to truncate mysql table data given time everyday?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created program for attendance download and using the data i display absent or present of employee. after 5 pm the attendance data table should be deleted. how can i do this with mysql scheduling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a query to delete record from the table like.

```
DELETE * FROM employee;
```

And place it to any file then after you have to set CRON on you hosting server. 
take reference for linux server https://kayako.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/5734656/Setting+up+a+server+cron+or+scheduled+task

IF you are using windows server you can go with 
http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html

Comment: why `*` . . . ?

Comment: As per the question "after 5 pm the attendance data table should be deleted"

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 :**

1. Go to Command Prompt (terminal)
2. type `which mysql`, You will get **Path to Mysql**
3. type `sudo crontab -e` to Edit Cron list
4. add below line in crontab :

   /usr/bin/mysql -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -Ddbname -e"TRUNCATE TABLE juice box"

It should work just fine.

It's because cron executes under an account which either does not have PATH defined or does not include a path to mysql.

---

**Option 2 :**

Now there is another option - using a [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)

```sql
CREATE EVENT update_date_column 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS NOW()
  DO TRUNCATE TABLE juicebox;
```

If you'll decide to go with an event approach:

- use [`SHOW EVENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-events.html) to list created events with their attributes (e.g. `status`)
- use [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) to check if the event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
- use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
- More on configuring event scheduler read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you give me the way to do above task.

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal, I updated the answer, Kindly go through it & Accept the answer if it resolves your question.

Comment: this is ok.. but can u give steps to make cron job on windows with php. i follow many videos but coudnt get clear idea. i want to make php script to download data from mysql and upload again it to another table..everyday in specific time.

Comment: @HarshaPriyalal, you want to run it on a lamp server or on your local windows machine ?

Comment: i solved it myself. thank you @luFFY, i did it with windows server. i used Windows Task Scheduler to do that.